# Change legacy login method to modern - PowerShell - Sharepoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, authentication

I have an authentication script below which is deemed as legacy and will soon be blocked by Microsoft.

How can I convert this script to use modern auth methods?

```
$site = https://mysite.sharepoint.com
$listName = "Events"
$user = myuser@mysite.onmicrosoft.com
$pwd = ConvertTo-SecureString "XXXXXXXXXXX" -AsPlainText -Force
 
$ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($site)
$credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($user,$pwd)
$ctx.Credentials = $credentials
$siteColl = $ctx.Web
$ctx.Load($siteColl)
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://morgantechspace.com/2021/09/connect-to-sharepoint-site-with-mfa-account-using-csom-and-powershell.html < Theres a guide here that should work without having to consent to MFA by the user :)

Answer (score 2):

You could use account with MFA to connect to SharePoint Online:

```
 #Add required references to OfficeDevPnP.Core and SharePoint client assembly
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline\3.29.2101.0\OfficeDevPnP.Core.dll") 
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client")
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime")
 
$siteURL = "https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/siten_name"
  
$AuthenticationManager = new-object OfficeDevPnP.Core.AuthenticationManager
$ctx = $AuthenticationManager.GetWebLoginClientContext($siteURL)
$ctx.Load($ctx.Web)
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()
  
Write-Host "Title: " $ctx.Web.Title -ForegroundColor Green
Write-Host "Description: " $ctx.Web.Description -ForegroundColor Green
```

For more information, you could refer to；
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/53244.sharepoint-connect-to-site-with-mfa-enabled-using-csom-and-pnp-powershell.aspx

Comment: This looks good but would require the user to sign in with MFA right? This script will run on task scheduler and needs to be fully automated.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to bypass MFA requirement is to use app only access. I have multiple scripts that run unattended using this approach on Azure. You can find more information on this Microsoft link:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/security-apponly-azureacs